# What does this sentence mean in this question (simulator can handle X inputs)?

Tags: verilog, flipflop, verification

In my book, one question requires me to find the verification sequence for a circuit. From what I understand, verification sequence must be such that every path is traversed. 
Then the book specifically mentions that to reduce the size of the simulation sequence, I have to assume that the simulator can handle X inputs and use X's whenever possible. Any explanation regarding this is highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Does X mean an unknown quantity or something crossing another thing?

Answer (score 1):

There is a clue in the question:

> To reduce the length of the simulation sequence

In this case, X is very probably a [don't care](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/63645/when-do-truth-tables-use-the-dont-care-term) term and it will therefore be removed as a node from the simulation (because it is irrelevant to the particular path being analysed).

As the term has been removed, the simulator will have fewer nodes to evaluate and therefore run faster.

Comment: If we're talking about a sequence of input stimulus, any X in the sequence will serve to sensitise both 0 and 1 values - that would make the run length shorter rather than permit the DUT to be simplified.